# How to add comparison in order condition of Yii2 query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, query-builder

So, I have SQL string with order by part like:

```
ORDER BY
    client_id>0 DESC,
    date_last DESC
```

I want to have similar condition in Query builder. What i need to add? (especially for "**client_id>0**")

```
$qr->orderBy([
    'client_id' => SORT_DESC,
    'date_last' => SORT_DESC,
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) to pass raw SQL statement:

```
$qr->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('client_id > 0 DESC, date_last DESC'));
```